# parsing out string in csv file type using perl

Tags: perl

I am using perl's `Tie::File` to parse through a .csv file and matching for a specific string, its actually the first string/header on the file.

The problem I am having might be my input file type. The tool that exports the data file can export in .csv or text which I tried and tested both.

Somehow, I am still NOT getting the match. My problem could be two-fold:
 (1) my regex is wrong and/or (2) the file type.

Sample file header/string (if I `cat` the file):

```
??Global  Mail_Date.Dat
```

Sample file header/string (if I open up in editor, apple's TextEdit.app)

```
Global  Mail_Date.Dat
```

Here's the octal dump:

```
0000000 377 376   G  \0   l  \0   o  \0   b  \0   a  \0   l  \0      \0
        feff 0047 006c 006f 0062 0061 006c 0020
0000020      \0   M  \0   a  \0   i  \0   l  \0   _  \0   D  \0   a  \0
        0020 004d 0061 0069 006c 005f 0044 0061
0000040   t  \0   e  \0   .  \0   D  \0   a  \0   t  \0  \r  \0  \n  \0
        0074 0065 002e 0044 0061 0074 000d 000a
```

Obviously, doing an os `cat` shows a leading `??` on the string.

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Tie::File;
use File::Copy;

    for (@ARGV) {
        tie my @lines, "Tie::File", $_;             
        #shift @lines if $lines[0] =~ /^Global/;
        if ($lines[0] =~ /^Global/) 
        {
             print "We have a match, remove the line ..";
             #shift @lines if $lines[0] =~ /^Global/;
             untie @lines; 
        }
        else
        { 
             print "No match found. Exit";
        }

}
```

Comment: The ?? could be a unicode BOM which TextEdit sees/skips. `cat` is just a plain "dump to output" and doesn't process the text in any way.

Comment: so, my regex should work then right? is there a better way to write it?

Comment: No, because Perl will also suck in the BOM. Your regex is looking for "Global" as the very first thing on a line - which it isn't - there's two unknown characters before it, so the regex never matches.

Comment: It seems like just removing the `^` in `/^Global/` would fix it, unless you expect the word "Global" on other lines. Maybe something like `/^.{0,2}Global/`.

Comment: @Chriszuma - thanks. i did try both your suggestions and still no luck. I did add the octal dump (see edit). I can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your file is encoded in utf16.

Try something like this:

```
binmode STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-16LE)';
while (<STDIN>) {
  if (m/Global/) {  # see note
    print "Matched Global on line $.\n";
  }
}
```

If you get a match then at least we know the encoding is correct.

To compensate for the BOM code-point, you could read in a single character after the `binmode` call:

```
binmode STDIN, ':encodeing(UTF-16LE)';
read(STDIN, my $buf, 1);
while (<STDIN>) {
  if (m/^Global/) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at the octal dump and notice the null character between each of your regular characters. That is, it's `G-\0-l-\0-o-\0-b-\0-a-\0-l-\0` and not `G-l-o-b-a-l`. This means your file is not in ASCII text. Is this in UTF8 or UTF16? If so, you have to use the `encoding` function when you open the file in Perl:

```
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-16)", $fileName)
    or die qq(Can't open file "$fileName" for reading);
```

If this is a csv file, you should try the [Text::CSV::Encoded](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-Encoded-0.10/lib/Text/CSV/Encoded.pm) module. This will help you parse your CSV file.